# Why create a new delegate object

Tags: c#, .net, events

What is the advantage of using

```
_books.RowChanged +=new DataRowChangeEventHandler(_books_RowChanged);
```

which VS automatically inserts, vs. using

```
_books.RowChanged += _books_RowChanged;
```

which seems to me to be both shorter and more efficient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference except that second form is less verbose. They both do the same exact thing.

Comment: IIRC the short form was introduced in .NET 2. The compiler will treat (convert) it as the long form.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: That's right. It's called implicit method group conversion.See "13.6. Method Group Conversions" in the ECMA-334 C# specification.